# data is saved but post request is failed when and give server error

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I try to save fields by action controller action method which return different view. But failed to do this: My Jquery code is:

```
$("#btnAdd").click(function () {
    var Product = {
        name: $("#txtProductName").val(),
        color: $("#ddlColor option:selected").val(),
        gage: $("#ddlGage option:selected").val(),
        rate: $("#txtrate").val()
    };
    $.ajax({
    });
    $.post("ProductTable", { Pro: JSON.stringify(Product) }, function (data) {
        $("#RightDiv").html(data);
        alert(data);
    });
});
```

and my controller action method on the same controller which return different view:

```
public ActionResult ProductTable()
{
        Product product = new Product();
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        product = serializer.Deserialize<Product>(Request.Form["Pro"]);
        productDB.addProduct(product);
        productManager.productTable = productDB.getAllProducts();
        return View(productManager);
}
```

Browser give me error:

```
HTTP500: SERVER ERROR - The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.
(XHR)POST - http://localhost:59008/Product/ProductTable
```

Comment: Try to enclose `Pro` in `""` like `$.post("ProductTable", { "Pro": JSON.stringify(Product) }, function (data) {........}`

Comment: same error nothing happen?

Comment: Ali why you are using `$,ajax` and `$.post` together. You need to remove this `$.ajax({});` statement.

Comment: which view are you trying to navigate to?

Comment: ProductTable has its on view. which have simple table which I want to get and display on other div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using MVC, it should handle the serialization/deserialization for you. You just need to make sure the object sent over matches the object you declare in MVC controller action parameter.

### Client-side

```
// Suggestions:
//   * use camelCase for javascript variables and functions
//   * jQuery .val() on selects should give you the selected value
//   * always use fully qualified Url generated by Html.Helper

$("#btnAdd").click(function () {
    var product = {
        name: $("#txtProductName").val(),
        color: $("#ddlColor").val(),
        gage: $("#ddlGage").val(),
        rate: $("#txtrate").val()
    };

    var createUrl = '@Url.Action("create", "product", new { area = "" })';

    $.post(createUrl, product, function (response) {
        $("#RightDiv").html(response);
        alert(response);
    });
});
```

## Server-side

```
// Suggestions:
//   * NEVER send your domain model back to the page! You should create 
//     a ViewModel to just include what you want to show the users

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CreateProductViewModel model)
{
    ...

    productDB.addProduct(new Product {
        Name = model.Name,
        Color = model.Color,
        Gage = model.Gage,
        Rate = model.Rate,
        // And other stuff like
        // CreatedBy = User.Identity.Name
    });

    // This looks weird to me too!
    productManager.productTable = productDB.getAllProducts();

    return View(productManager);
}
```

## The ViewModel

```
public class CreateProductViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Color { get; set; }
    public int Gage { get; set; }
    public double Rate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the inner exception if there is any? Also can you exam if Request.Form["Pro"] is NULL?

Comment: I repeat data is saved to database but post response is failed.
browser console give error: HTTP500: SERVER ERROR - The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Comment: Then the error should come from `productManager.productTable = productDB.getAllProducts();`, assuming `                productDB.addProduct(product);` saves the data. I HAVE no idea what your code is doing so I can only guess. Again, from your title you said your post request is failed but it is not. You did get the object from the post request and did save it successfully. It's just there somewhere in the code throws exception.

Comment: Note it can be just `$.post(createUrl, product, function (response) {` (and if OP had generated the view correctly, then it would also be `var product = $('form').serialize();`